# SQL Server: Full text catalog search issues

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm facing one problem regarding to Full text catalog Search Catalog in SQL Server 2005.
I have created a full text catalog and it is working fine but it does not work for special characters, I can search any strings except special characters.

The text I tried to search for the database is "2-(Dimethylamino)ethanol".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nvarchar(max)? Or what fieldtypes do you use? Because with nvarchar and UTF-8 encoding you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Hi There, There are different different fields like NVARCHAR(500), NVARCHAR(4000), NVARCHAR(255) and one catalog on all columns.

Comment: And when you use "SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE BAR LIKE '%2-(Dimethylamino)ethanol%'" you get 0 results?

Comment: When I try to search with like then it returns 1 result because record with the same name is exists in the database.

Comment: Can you post the query that you try to run? It's kind of hard to help you without solid examples

Comment: Here is the Query: SELECT TOP 600
                                DrugID ,
                                TradeNameRussia
                        FROM    DrugDatabase
                        WHERE   CONTAINS (TradeNameRussia, @SearchKeywordWild )